# using a count in c++

Tags: c++

In a text file the first 8 lines are text, which i don't need, so before i read the text file into a `vector`... I want to do a count so it basically starts reading the file at line 9;

```
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while ( getline(myfile, line) )
    {
        if count > 8;
        istringstream buffer(line);
        int x, y; 
        if (!(buffer >> x >> y));

        Station objName = {x, y};
        data_station.push_back(objName);
        count == count +1;
    }
}
```

this is where I'm up to, but i cant seem to sort out the count.

Comment: That code does not compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not *assignment*:

```
count == count +1;
```

but is an equality check meaning `count`'s value is never changed. Change to:

```
count++;
```

or:

```
// See comment from rhalbersma.
++count;
```

There is also a trailing semi-colon after (not to mention missing parenthesis):

```
if count > 8;
```

Change to:

```
if (count > 8)
{
    istringstream buffer(line);
    int x, y; 
    if (buffer >> x >> y) // Correction here also.
    {
        Station objName = {x, y};
        data_station.push_back(objName);
    }
}
```

Comment: or `++count;`, always good to get into that habit

Comment: @kingsindian, was updating answer with that.

Comment: @rhalbersma, why is that preferable?

Comment: @hmjd Because once `count` is not just a simple type, writing `count++` will definitely be bad practice (of course your compiler might still optimize away the unneccessary operations for simple inlined implementations, e.g. iterators, but neither should we give us dumber than we really are). Though you're right in that for an `int` it won't ever matter (but if it doesn't matter, why not make the better general solution the default?).

Comment: For builtin types it makes no difference, but for class types (e.g. iterators) `operator++` could have been overloaded, in which case pre-increment is never less efficient than post-increment. I prefer to only use post-increment when I need it.

Comment: thanks guys for your help, but i am still getting an error on if(count > 8)....the error, cannot determine which instance of function template "std::count" is intended

Comment: @jaylawson, get rid of `using namespace std;` from you code and use `std::` prefix where required. There is `std::count()` algorithm and it is clashing with the name of your `count` variable.

Comment: @hmjd ive tried that and still getting the same error

Comment: @jaylawson, that should work. Rename you `count` variable as a last resort but removing all `using namespace std;` from everywhere in your code (headers included) should fix this.

Comment: @hmjd thanks for you're help, im still getting that error, see above where im up to

Comment: @jaylawson, do _not_ use `std::count`: that is a function defined in algorithm. Just use `count`, and use `std::istringstream`. Also, don't edit the question in response to answers. It confuses everyone and makes nonsense of the posted answers.

Comment: @hmjd ok yeah i understand, getting used to these forums. ive done as you've said above if (count > 8), i already have std::istringstream and im getting another error: identifier "count" is undefined

Comment: @jaylawson, have you an `int count = 0;` somewhere??

Comment: @hmjd i have now and thats removed that error thanks

Comment: @hmjd ive solved the first part regarding the count, can i upload the rest of my code, where shall i upload it?

Comment: @jaylawson, ask a new question as this question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to use assignment rather than test for equality:

```
count = count + 1;
//    ^ here
```

However, this can be written more concisely as:

```
count++;
```

Also, note that the syntax of an `if` statement requires parentheses around the condition. To group many statements together as part of the `if`, introduce a block with `{` and `}`:

```
if (condition) {
  block of statements
}
```

So your code should look like this:

```
if (count > 8) {
  istringstream buffer(line);
  int x, y; 
  if (!(buffer >> x >> y)) {
    Station objName = {x, y};
    data_station.push_back(objName);
  }
}
```

It also seems that you have that inner `if` condition backwards. You want the block to be executed when the extractions succeed:

```
if (buffer >> x >> y)
```

Answer (score 0):

change this :`count == count +1;` to `count = count +1;`

better would be `count++;`